# PDF viewer Eclipse Plugin/Library which supports text extraction

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, eclipse-plugin, jpedal

I need an open source PDF viewer eclipse plugin/library from which i can select some text and copy/extract it.
I tried jPedal plugin (LGPL version). Its not extracting the selected text correctly.Sometimes it gets an extra character.I don't know whether it is working in the commercial version.
Is there any other alternative plugins available for the same?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use IcePDF plugin. Please look at
http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf

Comment: Yea..seems to be a good solution. Thank you :)